# Trying to figure out how to display something every second on java

Tags: java, timer

So basically im currently learning threading. Im trying to figure out how to test whether one second has passed. So my program should output `1 2 3 4 5` with each second that passes. Can anyone help with determing how to determine if a second has passed?

Edit:
Thank you everyone who helped out.

Comment: What time was the last update, what time is it now?  Take a look at `System.currentTimeMillis`.  Get the current time, sleep for a short period, what time is it now, how much time has passed, keep going till we get to 1000 milliseconds.  Of course, you could just use `Thread.sleep(1000)`...but why make these things easy ;)

Comment: Thread delays are not definite, if u ask java to sleep a thread for 1000 ms, its a request not a directive, Java might endup running the thread at a later time (say 1010 ms) but it wont be too far away from the original delay.

Comment: Have you tried `TimerTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just sleep for 1000 milliseconds as madprogrammer says.

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds)...// so 1000 means 1 second.
```

not put your logic in run method. your run method will run for each 1 sec as your thread is sleep for 1 second. hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Sanjay and Madprogrammer! I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I think you want output like this

```
int seconds = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(seconds++);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have a look on [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;    
for (;;) {    
    try {    
        Thread.sleep(1000);    
        // write your code over here    
        count++;    
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread and call the `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` method to sleep the thread for a particular interval.
Take a look at the below code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private int count;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("second " + (++count));
                Thread.sleep(1000);//1000 milliseconds, i.e. 1 second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```